# drop.na() not working on dataframe with Nan values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with Nan values. For some reason, df.dropna() doesn't work when I try to drop these rows. Any thoughts?

Example of a row:

```
30754   22  Nan Nan Nan Nan Nan Nan Jewellery-Women N
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/xxx/Desktop/CS 677/Homework_4/FashionDataset.csv')

df.dropna()
```

df.head().to_dict()

```
{'Unnamed: 0': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4},
 'BrandName': {0: 'life',
  1: 'only',
  2: 'fratini',
  3: 'zink london',
  4: 'life'},
 'Deatils': {0: 'solid cotton blend collar neck womens a-line dress - indigo',
  1: 'polyester peter pan collar womens blouson dress - yellow',
  2: 'solid polyester blend wide neck womens regular top - off white',
  3: 'stripes polyester sweetheart neck womens dress - black',
  4: 'regular fit regular length denim womens jeans - stone'},
 'Sizes': {0: 'Size:Large,Medium,Small,X-Large,X-Small',
  1: 'Size:34,36,38,40',
  2: 'Size:Large,X-Large,XX-Large',
  3: 'Size:Large,Medium,Small,X-Large',
  4: 'Size:26,28,30,32,34,36'},
 'MRP': {0: 'Rs\n1699',
  1: 'Rs\n3499',
  2: 'Rs\n1199',
  3: 'Rs\n2299',
  4: 'Rs\n1699'},
 'SellPrice': {0: '849', 1: '2449', 2: '599', 3: '1379', 4: '849'},
 'Discount': {0: '50% off',
  1: '30% off',
  2: '50% off',
  3: '40% off',
  4: '50% off'},
 'Category': {0: 'Westernwear-Women',
  1: 'Westernwear-Women',
  2: 'Westernwear-Women',
  3: 'Westernwear-Women',
  4: 'Westernwear-Women'}}
```

This is what I get when using df.head().to_dict()

Comment: Can you show us the code that you are using as of now ?

Comment: Could you paste the result of `df.head().to_dict()` into your question?

Comment: added the code above!

Comment: `dropna()` is not an in-place operation (not by default, anyway). You need to do `df = df.dropna()`, or `df.dropna(inplace=True)`.

Comment: neither worked, the latter deleted my df altogether

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[12,20,np.nan,np.nan],
               "col2":[10,np.nan,np.nan,40]})


df1 = df.dropna()

# df;
   col1  col2
0  12.0  10.0
1  20.0   NaN
2   NaN   NaN
3   NaN  40.0

# df1;
   col1  col2
0  12.0  10.0
```